# Generating random decimals between two decimals

Tags: c#, random, decimal

Whenever I say decimal, I mean `system.decimal` not the mathematical concept

```
decimal min = 5.62;
decimal max = 14.39;
```

How would I get a `system.decimal` that is randomly between the **range** of the above two decimals?

**Double != system.decimal**

FYI, I don't know how I can make my question clearer since more than half the people that read this only read 2 words and then flagged it as a duplicate.

Comment: Despite what you might think. The question this is a duplicate of answer is what you are looking for. **A decimal between two Decimals makes NO SENSE**  The reason it makes no sense is because 5.5 is a valid decimal value.

Comment: @Ramhound I am not looking for simply a random decimal, i don't know how clear i have to make this, The system.decimal has to be random, BUT bewteen a range of two system.decimal 's Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

y=mx+c.  Generate a 0<=X<1 FP random with NextDouble(), multiply it up by (Dmax-Dmin) into the right range, then add Dmin to shift the base.

Comment: As there are only so many values double can represent between 0 and 1 your algorithm does never select a whole bunch (most) possible decimals.

Answer (score 5):

Scale your decimals to ints or big ints (by multiplying by an appropriate power of 10.  Generate an int between them, then divide by a power of 10.

Or generate an int and then just scale it (linearly) between the decimals.

Comment: If you want a double you need to generate a double, not an int, unless you only want a short, fixed precision.

Comment: @Servy The C# decimal the OP refers to is not a double, it's a fixed point number and can be scaled: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 4):

```
public static double randomDouble(Random rand, double start, double end)
{    
    return (rand.NextDouble() * Math.Abs(end-start)) + start;
}
```

Comment: OP clearly asking about decimal, not double.

Comment: @BananaPoop http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.nextdouble.aspx

Comment: @spender at the time I wrote the post the OP's use of 'decimal' was ambigous between the data type and the mathematical concept (of which a double most certainly applies).  His specific statement, along with his comment here, state that he didn't even know that Random could generate a random double, the thought it could only generate Ints.

Comment: @BananaPoop if it really is imperative that you use decimal and not double, then just add my code to the link listed as the duplicate and change all of the data types in my method accordingly.

Comment: @BananaPoop - This is a duplicate despite the fact you think its different.  You have not given a valid reason or pointed out HOW its different.  A decmial value between two integers added to the lower integer does exactly what you want.

Comment: He wanted to generate a random Decimal, Just that, I need to generate a Random Decimal BUT it also has to be bewteen to other Decimals, random.next() only accepts ints, so i could get a decimal, but it would be bewteen to ints

Answer (score 3):

Here is a resource right here on Stack Overflow:

[Generating a random decimal in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609501/generating-a-random-decimal-in-c-sharp)

or you could try:

```
Random random = new Random();
double mathResult =  Math.Round((random.NextDouble() / 100), 3);
```

Hope this helps!