# Random numbers with decimals

Tags: c#, random, decimal

Im a beginner in C# I have created this program to generate 7 random numbers at display them in a console. But now I want to generate number with decimals in the range of 18.0-23.5. 
But I can't figure out how? I have tried with `Next.Double` but I can't get it to work. Help Please!

Here is my program:

```
int lotto1 = 0, lotto2 = 0, lotto3 = 0, lotto4 = 0, lotto5 = 0, lotto6 = 0, lotto7 = 0;
Random rnd = new Random();

Console.WriteLine("Din lottorad är:");
lotto1 = rnd.Next(1, 36);
Console.WriteLine("Nr1: " + lotto1);
lotto2 = rnd.Next(1, 36);
Console.WriteLine("Nr2: " + lotto2);
lotto3 = rnd.Next(1, 36);
Console.WriteLine("Nr3: " + lotto3);
lotto4 = rnd.Next(1, 36);
Console.WriteLine("Nr4: " + lotto4);
lotto5 = rnd.Next(1, 36);
Console.WriteLine("Nr5: " + lotto5);
lotto6 = rnd.Next(1, 36);
Console.WriteLine("Nr6: " + lotto6);
lotto7 = rnd.Next(1, 36);
Console.WriteLine("Nr7: " + lotto7);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/609501/generating-a-random-decimal-in-c-sharp

Comment: Do you just want one decimal place? Generate integer values between 180 and 235 then divide by ten.

Comment: at least search once before posting a question!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use [`NextDouble`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.nextdouble%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
 rnd.NextDouble() * (23.5-18.0) + 18.0
```

or more generically:

```
public double NextDouble(Random rnd, double min, double max)
{
    return rnd.NextDouble() * (max-min) + min;
}
```

Comment: You could also make the `NextDouble( Random, double, double )` method into an extension method so it can be used like `rnd.NextDouble( 18.0, 23.5 )`.

Comment: To follow up Kyle's suggestion, the method signature would be `public static double NextDouble(this Random rnd, double min, double max)`